# django render_to_response redirect to another view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm new in django
I have a render_to_response redirecting the user to the good url. But in the browser the url did not change so it's handle by the bad view...

here it is

```
return render_to_response('newworkflow.html/',    
{'form':form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my urls conf:

```
url(r'newworkflow/$','access_mgmt.views.newworkflowform'),
url(r'newuser/$','access_mgmt.views.newuser'),
```

once on the `newworkflow.html` i have a form, which is not handle by the good view, in fact it's handle by the one where is this render_to_response.

is it possible to change the URL in the browser in the same time with a `render_to_response`?

I user render_to_response because on both(source and target) i activated the csrf_token

Comment: It is hard to understand what your porblem is, show your `url configuration` and your related part of your `views` and expalin your problem with details.

Comment: i will update the question

Comment: I understand your question but I can't get it the flow of your codes, can you please put your complete codes in views

Answer (score 3):

`HttpResponseRedirect` can be used to redirect the client to a different URL.

`render_to_response` "Renders a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text."

It makes no sense to render a template into a response, if the client is going to ignore the body of the response and go to a different URL.

Instead, redirect the client to the appropriate URL, then provide the rendered response from the view associated with that URL.

Comment: Ok,even if i have the csrf_token activated on the source page and the target(target on which one i need to pass some arguments) because the both pages are forms

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by rendering a response to a client and redirecting it to another URL in the same step?

Comment: I want to keep informations about the forms filled before to go to the second form with this famous csrf_token activated. If i use the httpresponse i have a csrf_token error on the second form

Comment: The normal recommended behaviour for a POST is to accept the posted data, then redirect.  It's even in the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/).  It sounds like you've done something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## Understand "The URL"

You write

> is it possible to change the URL in the browser in the same time with a `render_to_response`?

I think you have a too-vague understanding of what "the URL" actually is.
If the browser asks for URL `X`, it will consider whatever you send it
to be the response for URL `X`, no matter what it is.

So if the server (you!) sends actual HTML content, the URL will
never change in the browser.

To make the URL change in the browser, you need to send a redirect response
(using Django's [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses)) to the browser.
The browser will take the URL `Y` contained therein
and make *another* request to the server with URL `Y` -- which is then
also shown in the browser's address bar.

The server would then send the HTML content for `Y`.
You cannot have both of these steps in one request: redirecting *and* sending content.